# Remotely copy between two servers from a third server with all ssh key set

Tags: python, linux, ssh, scp

I'm writing a deploy script using python, however after I finished it I found there might be not possible for what I thought.

The situation is like this.

I have 3 hosts.

- Host1: Ubuntu 12.04
- Host2: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP1
- Host3: Windows Server 2008 R2, with Cygwin 1.7.8 installed, also WinSSHD installed (I know normal ssh login is handled by WinSSHD, however rsync uses cygwin path, don't know what's wrong)

Now I need to run the remote copy command on Host1, to let the file transfer between Host2 and  Host3. I set all the ssh keys already, there's no problem to use scp after ssh login to any of the host.

However this will fail.

```
Host1:~$ ssh Host2 scp Host3:/myfile_on_Host3 /target_Host2_path
```

This command returns nothing, the scp should list the file copying but this just return nothing, and the file is not copied.

And this will fail too,

```
Host1:~$ scp Host3:/myfile_on_Host3 Host2:/target_Host2_path
```

The same , this returns nothing, not even a line.

However the following will work,

```
Host1:~$ ssh Host2
Host2:~$ scp Host3:/myfile_on_Host3 /target_Host2_path
```

So I'm totally confused here, why on a third host, I cannot do remote copy between two other servers ?

**Update:**

I made the file copying finally work using rsync rather than scp, but I am still totally confused.

So this will copy the file.

```
Host1:~$ ssh -A Host2 'rsync /myfile_on_Host2 Host3:/cygdrive/d/targetHost3Path/'
```

And the following will work too using scp.

```
Host1:~$ ssh -A Host2 'scp /myfile_on_Host2 Host3:D:\\targetHost3Path'
```

Comment: What does `ssh Host2 scp -v Host3:/myfile_on_Host3 /target_Host2_path` say?

Comment: Similarly, what does `scp -v Host3:/myfile_on_Host3 Host2:/target_Host2_path` say?

Comment: @tom You should post your update as the answer.